# What is the equivalent R code for this TensorFlow program in Python?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I am working on learning to solve equations in R and I am interested in doing it through TensorFlow (I already know how to do it using GA and Simulated Annealing).
I am building equivalent code in R for this python program which does Y = X + Z and solves for Z (found it in this [blog](https://medium.com/@liccowee/tensorflow-to-solve-simple-math-equation-27f42a44f0f1)). I have spent hours trying to find many variants of functions, searching them over the internet blogs and CRAN documentations.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1., 2.]])
y = tf.constant([[12., 4.]])
Z = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 2]))

yy = tf.add(x, Z)
deviation = tf.square(y - yy)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(deviation)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session();
sess.run(init)
for i in range(5000):
 sess.run(train_step)
print(sess.run(Z))
```

Below is the R code I have developed till now, trying many variants of the program in the process:

```
library(tensorflow)
x = tf$constant(c(1.,2.))
y = tf$constant(c(12,4))
Z = tf$Variable(tf$zeros(2,1))
yy = tf$add(x, Z)
deviation = tf$square(y - yy)

train_step = tf$optimizers$Adam(0.01)
```

Now I am not able to add the minimize() function to the train_step as I get an error which says its not an attribute of the optimizer. I have tried using evaluate, compile and other functions from both tensorflow and keras but have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Getting gradient is relatively easy, applying them to variable I cannot quite figure out how to do it on tf$Variable.. Maybe this still can help:

```
library(tensorflow)


optimizer <- tf$keras$optimizers$Adam(0.001)

x = tf$constant(c(1.,2.))
y = tf$constant(c(12,4))
Z = tf$Variable(tf$zeros(2,1))

with(tf$GradientTape() %as% tape, {
  yy = tf$add(x, Z)
  deviation = tf$square(y - yy)
})

grads <- tape$gradient(deviation,Z)
grads
tf.Tensor([-22.  -4.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
## now for adam part i cannot figure out how to apply it, usually you do:
# optimizer$apply_gradients(
#   purrr::transpose(list(grads, Z)) ## where Z would be model variables...
# )
```

EDIT: If someone knows how to solve this last step please edit/comment the solution.

Comment: Thanks for giving helping here @JacobJacox. I will try to use this and update on this thread.

Comment: I have not been able to make it work. Like I mentioned in question, I had used compile(object = yy, optimizer = optimizer, loss = deviation) and evaluate() earlier in a similar way, but these also need object to be of model type, like the Z in your code. Anyhow, thanks for the help